# How to create an avg measure in dax similar to the built-in chart function in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular

I am trying to create an average measure that calculates/acts the same way as the Average line in the Clustered column chart does.

[image]

The avg calculated measure that I want to create should also be a straight line showing the average of the whole year and not on the monthly level as it does now. I cannot get it to ignore the month context like the built-in average line function for column chart.

This is what I have tried:
Avg. Quantity:=AVERAGEX(VALUES(Dim_Time[Year]),[Quantity])

and then place it in the Clustered column with lines chart in the line area values box. As you can see on the picture it doesn't produce the same result.

How would the dax logic need be written to replicate the same reslut as the built-in average line function ?

[image]

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is the average measure you have written is being filtered by the month axis on your chart. You have to tell the measure to ignore that filter. Change cal[Month] to whatever your x-axis column is.

```
avg line = AVERAGEX(
                ADDCOLUMNS(
                    SUMMARIZE(
                        ALLSELECTED(cal[Month]),cal[Month]), 
                "@qty",CALCULATE([Quantity])),
            [@qty])
```